# Bind null value to a dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am using items from sharepoint list to be binded to a dropdown list. However, I want the first value in the dropdown to be empty. I cannot insert a null value in the sharepoint list item.

Please let me know how can I do it programmatically.
Below is the code I am using to bind the list to dropdownlist

```
   if (Fldname.Contains("xxxxxx"))
            {
                ddllist.DataSource = data.getCode();
                ddllist.DataTextField = "Title";
                ddllist.DataValueField = "Alphabetic_x0020_Code";
                ddllist.DataBind();
                ddllist.SelectedValue = string.Empty;
                ddllist.Width = 120;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there has to be something like this. Where 0 is the position you want the new item be - which is the first in this case. Can do this after the databinding.

```
ddllist.Items.Insert(0 , string.empty);
```